# In Tomcat 9, can AutoDeploy be turned off programatically

Tags: java, tomcat, hardening

We use tomcat 9 with spring/hibernate. Obviously its a production code and the tomcat manager is not there. For the tomcat hardening we are trying to turn off the "autoDeploy"  via code dynamically. We can do that in server.xml as :

```
<Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="false" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
```

Can that be done? Is there a way to do this programatically?

EDIT: Code attempted:

```
package test.servlet;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.management.MBeanServer;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.Registry;

public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    ObjectName oname = null;
    MBeanServer mBeanServer = null;

    public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String name = request.getParameter("app");

        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

        try {
            oname = new ObjectName("Catalina:type=Deployer,host=localhost");
            mBeanServer = Registry.getRegistry(null, null).getMBeanServer();
            if (!isDeployed(name) && !isServiced(name)) {
                writer.println("deploying application -> " + name);
                addServiced(name);
                try {
                    // Perform new deployment
                    check(name);
                } finally {
                    removeServiced(name);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    protected void check(String name) throws Exception {
        String[] params = { name };
        String[] signature = { "java.lang.String" };
        mBeanServer.invoke(oname, "check", params, signature);
    }

    protected void addServiced(String name) throws Exception {
        String[] params = { name };
        String[] signature = { "java.lang.String" };
        mBeanServer.invoke(oname, "addServiced", params, signature);
    }

    protected boolean isDeployed(String name) throws Exception {
        String[] params = { name };
        String[] signature = { "java.lang.String" };
        Boolean result = (Boolean) mBeanServer.invoke(oname, "isDeployed", params, signature);
        return result.booleanValue();
    }

    protected boolean isServiced(String name) throws Exception {
        String[] params = { name };
        String[] signature = { "java.lang.String" };
        Boolean result = (Boolean) mBeanServer.invoke(oname, "isServiced", params, signature);
        return result.booleanValue();
    }

    protected void removeServiced(String name) throws Exception {
        String[] params = { name };
        String[] signature = { "java.lang.String" };
        mBeanServer.invoke(oname, "removeServiced", params, signature);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code. You can definitely do this via Java code.

Comment: posted the code above...check(...) method will do deployment from manager app. getting mBeanServer and doing same, we can deploy it. but we cannot undeploy it.

Comment: Oh... you want to disable `autoDeploy` from within a running application? That's weird. I thought you were using Tomcat-embedded and couldn't figure out how to programmatically-apply the `autoDeploy=false` while configuring Tomcat. Is this some kind of attempt to enforce security-from-the-inside (of the application) instead of applying this change externally (from `server.xml`)?

Comment: Yes! This is to enforce security with out restart.

Comment: If you really want to control the container containing your web application, you are better off using an embedded container deployment where your application actually launches Tomcat itself with your application deployed into it. You could also use Spring Boot if you are a fan of the Spring ecosystem to do the same kind of thing. I'm not sure you can stop and restart a `<Host>` from within an application.

Comment: Another option you might have to "enforce" security would be to cause the context (web application) to fail to initialize if it detects it's running under an unacceptable configuration. So you can check to see if `autoDeploy` is enabled and then bomb with an error message if it's enabled. So it answer the question you asked, but it may achieve your goal of enforcing some security policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I guess you would have to disable deployOnStartup and autoDeploy both.*

**Reference from the Tomcat 9 docs for host :**

> **autoDeploy :**
> This flag value indicates if Tomcat should check periodically for new
> or updated web applications while Tomcat is running. If true, Tomcat
> periodically checks the appBase and xmlBase directories and deploys
> any new web applications or context XML descriptors found. Updated web
> applications or context XML descriptors will trigger a reload of the
> web application. The flag's value defaults to true.

> **deployOnStartup** : This flag value indicates if web
> applications from this host should be automatically deployed when
> Tomcat starts. The flag's value defaults to true.

If you disable deployOnStartup and autoDeploy, then you would need to explicitly configure the manager app via a Context element in server.xml and then use it to deploy additional WAR files/directories.

Note : You can disable auto deploy via setting - `autodeploy="false"` in your `server.xml` file.

Read more at : [Apache Tomcat 9 Configuration Reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/host.html)

Comment: True, I have said that in the question it can be done in XML config. But how do we do that programatically? That is the whole crux of the question.

Comment: We want to deploy all wars and then programatically seal it shut.

Comment: You will have to do it via server.xml.

Answer (score 1):

No, it cannot be, as you cannot set `autoDeploy="false"` from Java code.

The only way to configure this, is to do it in the `server.xml`.